# How is it possible that one computer access another computer's localhost(127.0.0.1)?

Tags: networking, webserver, localhost, loopback, jekyll

I know what does localhost, `127.0.0.1`, means. It means *loopback address*, which can make a computer use as remote system. Of course, I know **it is not possible that localhost cannot be accessed from another computer** (node).

However, **it happened**. I am curious why this is happened..

## Problem explain

### Environment

- Node A: 192.168.9.21 (Windows 10)
- Node B: 192.168.9.22 (Centos 8 Stream)

I am keeping a blog with github pages, which use *Jekyll* with *Ruby*.
And this ran on Linux machine (Node B, 192.168.9.22) for test.

Below image is the description of my environment.

[image: Network description]

### Situation

I execute Jekyll server with Ruby in my Node B (Linux machine)

```bash
[root@dev-desktop TyeolRik.github.io]# uname -a
Linux dev-desktop 4.18.0-408.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 18 17:42:52 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@dev-desktop TyeolRik.github.io]# ifconfig | grep 'inet'
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:a8ff:fe12:6327  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:c4ff:fe87:1d10  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet 192.168.9.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.9.255
        inet6 fe80::b62e:99ff:fece:dbe3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        inet6 fe80::e41b:acff:fe76:5180  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::3cc3:a1ff:feac:ec90  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
[root@dev-desktop TyeolRik.github.io]# bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /root/TyeolRik.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: /root/TyeolRik.github.io
       Destination: /root/TyeolRik.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 1.337 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/root/TyeolRik.github.io'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

You can see that the IP of Node B (Linux machine) is 192.168.9.22.
And I ran the Jekyll server with the command `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

On the Node A (Windows), I turn on Chrome and access 127.0.0.1:4000. And this works.

[image: Chrome Access]

To prove that I access on Windows machine (without delusion),
I also show you my **Network configuration** which can be shown on Windows setting.

## Question

**How this is possible?**

* At first, I wrote this question on "Network Engineering Stack Exchange". But, it was closed due to off-topic.

## Added

```bash
[root@dev-desktop ~]# ss -tulpn
Netid            State             Recv-Q            Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port            Process
udp              UNCONN            0                 0                                    0.0.0.0:5353                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1011,fd=13))
udp              UNCONN            0                 0                                  127.0.0.1:323                                0.0.0.0:*                users:(("chronyd",pid=1026,fd=5))
udp              UNCONN            0                 0                                    0.0.0.0:37490                              0.0.0.0:*                users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1011,fd=15))
udp              UNCONN            0                 0                                       [::]:5353                                  [::]:*                users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1011,fd=14))
udp              UNCONN            0                 0                                       [::]:47088                                 [::]:*                users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1011,fd=16))
udp              UNCONN            0                 0                                      [::1]:323                                   [::]:*                users:(("chronyd",pid=1026,fd=6))
udp              UNCONN            0                 0                                          *:49805                                    *:*                users:(("java",pid=3818,fd=337))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6013                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=3262,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6014                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=3472,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6015                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=45778,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:4000                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("bundle",pid=66201,fd=8))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6016                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=47351,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6017                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=47502,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6018                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=65822,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:40327                              0.0.0.0:*                users:(("node",pid=2263,fd=18))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                  0.0.0.0:8629                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("docker-proxy",pid=49044,fd=4))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                  0.0.0.0:22                                 0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=1099,fd=3))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 5                                  127.0.0.1:631                                0.0.0.0:*                users:(("cupsd",pid=1154,fd=7))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6010                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=2120,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6011                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=2380,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                127.0.0.1:6012                               0.0.0.0:*                users:(("sshd",pid=2464,fd=13))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6013                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=3262,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6014                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=3472,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6015                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=45778,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6016                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=47351,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                        *:38080                                    *:*                users:(("java",pid=47090,fd=132))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6017                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=47502,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6018                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=65822,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                        *:8080                                     *:*                users:(("java",pid=47090,fd=440))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                     [::]:8629                                  [::]:*                users:(("docker-proxy",pid=49052,fd=4))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                     [::]:22                                    [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=1099,fd=4))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 5                                      [::1]:631                                   [::]:*                users:(("cupsd",pid=1154,fd=6))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6010                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=2120,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6011                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=2380,fd=12))
tcp              LISTEN            0                 128                                    [::1]:6012                                  [::]:*                users:(("sshd",pid=2464,fd=12))
```

Comment: Caching????????

Comment: @davidgo No. I've never turn on the server on windows machine and also, I pressed "Ctrl + F5" on Chrome which is shortcut of Refreshing cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you are doing local port forwarding. I guess you are using putty and have it configured similar to the following command:`ssh -L 4000:127.0.0.1:4000 user@192.168.9.22`.

If you do not have a SSH connection or something similar open, it could also be a reverse proxy. In this case please append the output of `ss -tulpn` to your question.

Comment: I edited my question as you said. Of course, Node A and B are connected with ssh (and also authorized with pubkey)

Comment: @TyeolRik Well, there's your answer. You're forwarding that port. Making it available as if it was local is exactly what forwarding does.

Comment: And also I am not using putty. I am just using Windows terminal ( Actually Powershell ) with normal ssh. There is no putty installed in Node A (Windows machine)

Comment: @gronostaj Would you tell me more specifically? I can't see where is hint of forwarding that port. The code snippet, which shows the result of ```ss -tulpn```, is captured in Node B(Linux machine). And Chrome is opened in Node A (Windows machine)

Comment: WOW.... Thanks to @dirdi. There is "Auto forwarded" by VScode (remote ssh).. I got a popup menu. and it said "Origin: Auto Forwarded". [VS Code forward](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting) What a magnificent technology!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings.

Unless `192.168.9.22:4000` is set up as proxy, there's some real magic going on.

You've got duplicate `192.168.9.22` addresses here, so the setup's already a mess.

Comment: Well.. I don't know how to make proxy setting. But, If there is, company network would make it work. But the truth is, my co-worker, whose IP address is 192.168.9.**23**, cannot access on 127.0.0.1:4000 unsurprisingly...